# EnvoyFilter: Apply ExtAuthz filter followed by Lua filter

Tags: kubernetes, lua, istio, envoyproxy

I am trying to figure out out to contruct an `EnvoyFilter` (using v3 API) to be used in conjunction with Istio and OAuth2-Proxy (as external Authz service).

Essentially I need a setup that will call an `ExtAuthz` in order to authenticate, and also retrieve the header `x-auth-request-email` and rename it to `kubeflow-userid`. I am having quite a bit of difficulty understanding how Envoy chains filters.

My current attempt is as follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  filters:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: GATEWAY
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
            subFilter:
              name: envoy.filters.http.jwt_authn
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value:
        name: envoy.filters.http.ext_authz
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.ext_authz.v3.ExtAuthz
          http_service:
            server_uri:
              uri: http://oauth2-proxy.oauth2-proxy.svc.cluster.local:4180
              cluster: outbound|4180||oauth2-proxy.oauth2-proxy.svc.cluster.local
              timeout: 10s              
            authorizationRequest:
              allowedHeaders:
                patterns:
                - exact: cookie
              authorizationResponse:
                allowedUpstreamHeaders:
                  patterns:
                    # - exact: "kubeflow-userid"
                    - exact: "authorization"
                    - exact: "x-auth-request-email"    
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER # should this be NETWORK_FILTER instead?
    match: # how do I define the context here?
      #context: GATEWAY
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
            subFilter:
              name: envoy.filters.http.jwt_authn
    patch:
      operation: MERGE # what should this be?
      value:
        name: envoy.filters.http.lua
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua
          inline_code: |
            function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
              headers = request_handle:headers()
              request_handle:headers():add("kubeflow-userid", headers:get("x-auth-request-email))
            end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case the filter chain is defined by

- the subFilter.name you define in the match part
- the name of your filter in the patch part

I find it easier to understand it as two separat filters (I adjusted the names):

Your `ExtAuthz` filter is inserted before the filter `envoy.filters.http.router` with the name `custom.ext_authz`.

```
[...]
    match:
      context: GATEWAY
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
            subFilter:
              name: envoy.filters.http.router
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value:
        name: custom.ext_authz
```

and the `lua` filter is inserted after the `custom.ext_authz` filter with the name `custom.lua`.

```
    match: 
      context: GATEWAY
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
            subFilter:
              name: custom.ext_authz
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_AFTER
      value:
        name: custom.lua
[...]
```

So the filter chain looks something like:

~ -> custom.ext_authz -> custom.lua -> envoy.filters.http.router -> ~

You can verify your setup with the envoy dashboard:

- Run `istioctl dashboard envoy ingress-gateway-<id>.istio-system`
- Open your browser on the url if it doesn't open automatically
- Press `config_dump`

There all filters are shown (search them by name), so you can verify your setup and the order.